# Make: re-assigning variable within recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a question regarding the scope of variables within a Makefile.

I have several targets, all of which execute the same command, but some parameters of the command need to change depending on the target.

To try eliminating redundancy, I'm attempting to refactor these targets such that each target simply sets up some variables and then a generic target is called later which uses these variables.

For example,

```
target1:
    COMMAND="../bin/release/prog1 input"
    TITLE=PROG1
    OUTFILE=PROG1.pdf
    make targetN
target2:
    COMMAND="../bin/release/prog2 input"
    TITLE=PROG2
    OUTFILE=PROG2.pdf
    make targetN
..
..
targetN:
    $(COMMAND) | grep RESULTS > results.csv
    gnuplot -e "TITLE=$(TITLE)" prog.plot
    ...
    ..
```

Here target1 and target2 set-up their "target-specific" variables, then call targetN.
The intention is that targetN would then use these variables and run the general commands with them.

Problem: targetN does not see the values of these variables set in target1 and/or target2.
Can anyone shed some light on this?  I have tried searching for information regarding scope among targets, but did not find anything useful.  Perhaps this issue is not related to scope at all and is an entirely different problem.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve with this scheme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each command runs in its own subshell, so variables set in one command are not visible in another.

But there's a better way to do what you intend: [target-specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific).

```
target1: COMMAND="../bin/release/prog1 input"
target1: TITLE=PROG1
target1: OUTFILE=PROG1.pdf

target2: COMMAND="../bin/release/prog2 input"
target2: TITLE=PROG2
target2: OUTFILE=PROG2.pdf

...
...

target1 target2:
    $(COMMAND) | grep RESULTS > results.csv
    gnuplot -e "TITLE=$(TITLE)" prog.plot
    ...
```

Or if the pattern is really as strict as what you're showing us, you can get away with a pattern rule:

```
target1 target2 : target% :
    ../bin/release/prog$* input | grep RESULTS > results.csv
    gnuplot -e "TITLE=PROG$*" prog.plot
    ...
```

Comment: From the link you posted, it says that target-specific values are only available within the context of a target's recipe.  Doesn't this mean then that if I were to set a target-specific variable in target1, for instance, that this would not be available to targetN?

Comment: That's correct, but in my first proposed solution there's no need to `make targetN` at all. But if you really want to pass these variables to a sub-make, I can show you how.

Comment: @Beta, exactly what I need! This works. I tried navigating the maze of recursive makes and attempts at using phony targets without success (great as they all are for their intended purposes, of course). Thank you.